# Extract value from org-babel-get-src-block-info

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have this elisp code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :dir ~/org/test

(defun test ()
  (setq args '(org-babel-get-src-block-info))
  (cdr (assoc ':dir args)))
(test)

#+END_SRC
```

But when I execute the code block, I get a message saying that no output was produced... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not use tag `elisp` for questions about how to use Elisp. It's for questions about the nature of the language, compared to other languages, in particular other Lisp dialects. Thx.

Comment: @Stefan I just edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Unquote `'(org-babel-get-src-block-info)` and
2. Replace `(cdr (assoc ':dir args))` with `(assoc-default :dir (nth 2 args))`

That is:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :dir ~/org/test
(defun test ()
  (setq args (org-babel-get-src-block-info))
  (assoc-default :dir (nth 2 args)))
(test)
#+END_SRC
```

Or:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :dir ~/org/test
(let* ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info))
       (params (nth 2 info)))
  (assoc-default :dir params))
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Works great -- thanks Jagrg! If you want to write this up as a single function, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you are quoting the call to `org-babel-get-src-block-info`, so the function is never called. Second, you probably want to change the test function to something like this:

```
(defun test()
   (let ((args (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))
      args))
```

until you understand what the call to `org-babel-get-src-block-info` returns. In fact, it would be a good idea to try doing `M-: (org-babel-get-src-block-info) RET`, so you can see clearly what the function returns. Third, babel has strange ideas about what to do with the output. In this particular case, you might want to set `:results raw` (despite the disadvantage that you have to delete the results by hand every time), so as to avoid the strange interpretation.